# "Incorrect number of parameters" error while consuming a web service

Tags: soap, asp-classic

I have this web service:
https://pgws.bpm.bankmellat.ir/pgwchannel/services/pgw?wsdl

the web service has `bpPayRequest` method which takes 10 parameters as web service provider defined it as below:

```
bpPayRequest(long terminalID, string username, string password, long orderID, long amount, string localDate, string localTime, string additionalData, string callbackURL, long payerID)
```

i'm using ASP Classic and this is my codes:

```
<%
RedirectURL = "http://" & Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & "/Frontend/epayverify_l2.asp"

set oSOAPay = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
oSOAPay.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
on error resume next
oSOAPay.mssoapinit(webServiceAddr)
oSOAPay.ConnectorProperty("UseSSL") = False 
if err.number <> 0 Then
    if DebugMode Then
        rwbr err.description
        response.end
    Else
        epayAction = false
        this_error = "banknotresponse"
        Exit for
    End if
End if
on error goto 0

result = oSOAPay.bpPayRequest(_
    CLng(str_terminal), _
    CStr(M_ID), _
    "password", _
    CLng(int_orderID), _
    CLng(Amount), _
    "20130610", _
    "102030", _
    "", _
    CStr(RedirectURL), _
    0)
%>
```

and this is the `result = oSOAPay.bpPayRequest` parameters with value:

```
oSOAPay.bpPayRequest( 709499, "11111", "password", 2, 1000, "20130610", "102030", "", "http://mitranik.com/Frontend/epayverify_l2.asp", 0 )
```

The problem is when i run this code, i'm getting this error.

```
Client:Incorrect number of parameters supplied for SOAP request HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect. - Client:Unspecified client error. HRESULT=0x80070057: The parameter is incorrect.
```

am i missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

The web method is expecting 9 parameters:

1. long terminalID
2. string username
3. string password
4. long orderID
5. long amount
6. string localDate
7. string localTime
8. string callbackURL
9. long payerID

However when you consume it, you give it 10 parameters:

1. CLng(str_terminal)
2. CStr(M_ID)
3. "password"
4. CLng(int_orderID)
5. CLng(Amount)
6. "20130610"
7. "102030"
8. ""
9. CStr(RedirectURL)
10. 0

Parameter #8 (which is fixed empty string) is the culprit, just get rid of it:

```
result = oSOAPay.bpPayRequest(_
    CLng(str_terminal), _
    CStr(M_ID), _
    "password", _
    CLng(int_orderID), _
    CLng(Amount), _
    "20130610", _
    "102030", _
    CStr(RedirectURL), _
    0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but seems it doesn't change the error. I removed the empty string (which was for `Additional Data` parameter as Web Service Provider documentation says).
How you found that the web service expects 9 parameters? because follow the webservice documentation it expects 10 parameters and that empty string stands for "Additional Data" [String] data type

Comment: @mhesabi I took the signature you posted: `bpPayRequest(long terminalID, string username, string password, long orderID, long amount, string localDate, string localTime, string callbackURL, long payerID)` and counted one by one. There is only 9 parameters, no "Additional Data" in there, the documentation is probably wrong/outdated. If it's a third party web service worth contacting their support on this matter.

Comment: you are right, it was typo and i missed that parameter. edited my question.
btw, I've contacted support already but they don't know about ASP classic